# what's the matter with contex:this in AS

Tags: java, android

It is highly probable that my question is extremely stupid. I'm so sorry in advanced, its my first project in AS and i have this problem following a yb tutorial!

```
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Context:this,R.layout.spinner_item_maladies,maladies);
main_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

the problem is with `context:this`

Comment: does this code belong on an activity class?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `this` only. it is not `context:this`.

So it should be like this.

```
ArrayAdapter <String> adapter;
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item_maladies,maladies);
main_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I hope it clears.

You can refer to this if you still have the proble.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView